# Moving element in source code only on responsive website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I was wondering what would be the best solution to move certain element of the responsive page, which is displayed in footer on live website, on top in source code only.

[EXAMPLE](http://bit.ly/KIrUMU)

Like this site has h1 seo-block right after body tag in source code but on live website this content is displayed at the bottom. They use absolute positioning to fix this.

```
#subfooter{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

My question is how could I do this on responsive design because absolute positioning doesn't work best there unless we would use a lot of @media queries for this class only. Are there any other better css/js/jquery solutions for this?

Comment: You know that Google can detect SEO texts, that are moved to less relevant positions, because it parses the CSS? You are going to risk to lose your rank with such a technique.

Comment: @feeela document.getElementById('stay').appendChild(document.getElementById('') );   Is using this solution gonna be bad for SEO ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do so via CSS alone. You need to move the part in question using JavaScript.

jQuery example:

```
jQuery( 'body' ).append( jQuery( '#subfooter' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to live with the (currently) [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), you can achieve this with [the flexible box layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

([live demo](http://jsbin.com/AmIMoHIV/1/edit?html,output))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Flexbox</title>
<style>
  body { 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #source-top {
    order: 2;
  }
  #source-bottom {
    order: 1;
  }
</style>  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="source-top">Source top</div>
  <div id="source-bottom">Source bottom</div>
</body>
</html>
```